# Defining protocols without parameters

Tags: objective-c, objective-c-protocol

I am trying to define a protocol method without adding parameters but couldn't find the correct syntax.

Here is the definition (it has a syntax error)

```
- (void)cameraOverlayView:(CameraOverlayView *)cameraOverlay didTakePhoto;
```

I don't want to pass any values with the second parameter. My aim is only to signal that something happened to the delegate instance.

How should I write the definition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
- (void)cameraOverlayViewDidTakePhoto:(CameraOverlayView *)cameraOverlay;
```

Comment: Thanks! :) I think I will have problems getting used to Objective-C syntax for a long time.

Comment: Naming can be tough. This could even be - (void)didCaptureImageWithCameraOverlayView:(CameraOverlayView*)aCameraOverlayView;

Comment: @uchuugaka 1. no, it's simple, 2. No, it couldn't, look up Cocoa naming conventions.

Comment: Oh geez. It is tough for people new to it. See SO every day. And yes it could. Look at plenty of delegate methods. It could be named anything appropriate if you are the author. Take Photo is not as honest about what the action really is. Is ring a scanner is the same.

Answer (score 3):

Your the second part of the method is not formatted correctly:

```
- (void)cameraOverlayView:(CameraOverlayView *)cameraOverlay didTakePhoto;
```

Because of the space, it's expecting a parameter. Instead, work the `didTakePhoto` part into the method name, like:

```
- (void)cameraOverlayViewDidTakePhoto:(CameraOverlayView *)cameraOverlay;
```

Answer (score 1):

basically in objective c you can't have method name parts dangling after parameters...
so:

illegal:

```
-(void)methodWith:(int)theInt forMyMom;
```

normal:

```
-(void)methodForMyMomWithInt:(int)theInt;
```

legal but strange

```
-(void)method:(int)theInt :(int)theOtherInt;
```

with the selector: @selector(method::)

Answer (score -3):

This is an issue of Objective-C convention. You could rewrite it as:

```
- (void)cameraOverlayView:(CameraOverlayView *)cameraOverlayViewDidTakePhoto;
```